# Using NLTK in python, while performing Named Entity Recognition, namedEnt.draw() method not giving any output?

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have imported NLTK library and I am trying to generate a parse tree that generates chunks of named entities in the document. Here is the code sample:

```
    train_text = state_union.raw("2005-GWBush.txt")
    sample_text = state_union.raw("2006-GWBush.txt")

    custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)

    tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(sample_text)

    #print tokenized

    def process_content():
        try:
            for i in tokenized:
            words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)

            namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged)

            namedEnt.draw()


        except Exception as e:
            print (str(e))


    process_content()
```

When I run this code, the "namedEnt.draw()" method generates no output. There's no window that opens that displays the parsed document tree of named entities. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?
Also, when I print(namedEnt), it gives me the right output. It prints the chunks of named entities.

Comment: is TkInter installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed and running.

Comment: But I did not import it while running the above program. Do I need to?